# Amongst the 60% of the population that have different size feet, is the left foot 80% of the time the larger foot?

Tags: physiology

http://www.quadcitiesrealestate.com/SHOE_ARTICLES/Different_Size_Feet.htm says:

> First, you should know that **60% of the population have different size
>   feet** that we will pick up when measuring. Contrary to popular belief,
>   the **left foot is 80% of the time, the larger foot**.  It is explained
>   that 80% of the population is right hand dominant.  That to do any
>   work, you can not lift with the right hand and the right foot
>   forward.  Everything is in the same plain and unbalanced.  Instead you
>   put your right hand forward and your left foot forward.  This creates
>   a three legged stool or tripod and is stable for lifting.  It also
>   exercises the foot opposite the dominant hand more, thus the slight
>   variance in the size of the feet.

How true is it?

Answer (score 2):

A [study done in 1978](http://worldtracker.org/media/library/Science/Science%20Magazine/science%20magazine%201978-1979/root/data/Science%201978-1979/pdf/1978_v200_n4347/1747016.pdf) seems to show it isn't that simple:

> In this 
>   study, asymmetries in the size of the two feet were strongly related to sex and hand- 
>   edness, right-handed males having larger right feet and right-handed females having 
>   larger left feet, the reverse being seen in non-right-handed individuals.

For males, the larger foot is most often on the *same* side as the dominant hand, and the opposite is true for females.

If a **significant** proportion of people with different sized feet were female, that would make the claim at plausible. However, the study above did not bear that out. Among those studied, 70% of males had different sized feet compared to 80% of females.